# Executing buildsteps in buildbot on other clients

Tags: python, buildbot, build-system

I am trying to find out if I can execute certain buildsteps on another machine than the build client in the same build. For instance, one path of the build process includes that the final zip should just be packaged if 2 other machines did run successfully a unit test. Can someone point me to a link or explain how that could be possible with buildbot?

```
(client3)                        ↗  unittest    ↘ 
(client2)                      ↗   other tests    ↘
(client1) → git sync → compile → sign executables → zip → publish
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mozilla made a useful presentation about this topic in 2013. To me it seems that `controlling build` is the term you are looking for.

> Buildbot best practice: manage parallel execution from a controlling
>   build.

http://releng.polymtl.ca/RELENG2013/html/slides/buildbot-talk/index.html?full#release-process-lines

Personally I like the flock concept. That was a proposal a few years ago where a build job could have several 'starting points'. But I am not sure what the progress is on this

[image]